# What is the point of using realm-android-adapter?

Tags: android, realm

There is no mention of why. I still have to code all the view holder stuff, so what is the benefit of using it instead of RecyclerView.Adapter?

Just curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It automatically adds a RealmChangeListener to your RealmResults, thus automatically calling `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` when the underlying elements are written to. Therefore you don't need to write the code to keep your adapter in sync with the results.